# listening to music for a siyum during the 9 days

Tags: halacha, music, nine-days, siyum, three-weeks

I saw that Maran Harav Ovadia Yosef said that one can listen to music for a siyum during the 3 weeks. I was curious if this also applies to the 9 days and maybe even the week of Tisha Be'Av. I want Marans answer ideally.

Comment: I heard a rabbi say that he once went to a very conservative shul during the nine days, he heard music playing for a type of exercise class.  When he brought it up to the rabbi he said it was fine as it was not for the purpose of enjoyment.  I’m just telling the story not giving advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes, he can.**

Sources from *Laws of the Holidays, p. 285*, by Rabbi Yonatan Nacson of Yechaveh Da'at and https://instarabbiapp.com/:

> Yechaveh Daat 6:34; Halichot Olam, vol. 2, p. 138; Chazon Ovadia, Arba Taaniyot, p. 151; Torat HaMoadim, Ben HaMetzarim 5:4; Yalkut Yosef, Ben HaMetzarim, p. 208.